# Pythonic way to find max of columns in df within a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, max

I have a dictionary which contains several, identically formatted, dataframes.  I would like to find the max value of a specific column in all dataframes.  I could iterate through the dictionary, but I assume there must be a more pythonic way to do it.

For example, say I have two dataframes (shortened for example, but they will have more numeric columns than just age:

```
b = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Ted', 'Ben', 'Frank', 'Allen'],
     'age': [22,38,26,35]})
g = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Emily', 'Anna', 'Amy', 'Steph'],
     'age': [18,23,44,21]})
```

Contained within a dict:

```
dict = {'Boys': b,
     'Girls': g}
```

Then I'd assume something like this would work, but it doesn't because the dictionary is not subscriptable, which I think I understand, I'm just not sure the correct way to do it:

```
Max = max(dict.values()['age'])
```

Is there a better way without iterating through in a loop?  (if it wasn't clear, the answer should be 44 in this example)

Comment: Why don't you just append the dataframes and then compute the max value?

Comment: `max(df['age'].max() for df in d.values())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following:

```
from itertools import chain
result = max(chain.from_iterable(df['age'] for df in d.values()))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
44
```

Notice that I renamed the dictionary as `d` because you should not use built-in names such as `dict`.

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  I'm just going to wait a little bit and see if anyone has any suggestions for a way to do it without another library (just for my own curiosity), otherwise I'll mark this as correct.  And yes, good point.  It was just a quick example.

Comment: itertools is a built-in library

Comment: I didn't.  I gave you an upvote and marked as correct.

Comment: @BenjaminBrannon Sorry for the confusion, someone downvoted and then changed it's mind.

Answer (score 4):

#### Setup

```
b = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Ted', 'Ben', 'Frank', 'Allen'],
     'age': [22,38,26,35]})
g = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Emily', 'Anna', 'Amy', 'Steph'],
     'age': [18,23,44,21]})

d = {'B': b, 'G': g}
```

#### `pd.concat` and `max(level=0)`

```
pd.concat(d).age.max(level=0)

B    38
G    44
Name: age, dtype: int64
```

#### or just `max`

```
pd.concat(d).age.max()

44
```

#### less Pandas

This is short, but not necessarily the best.  I'm suspicious of this for bigger data.

```
max(map(lambda x: max(d[x].age), d))

44
```

#### Generator

Because I can

```
def y(d):
    for x in d:
        yield from d[x].age

max(y(d))

44
```

Comment: Does concat builds a big DataFrame?

Comment: Yes it does, which might be a time sink depending on the size of the data.  Well it just depends on a number of factors.

Comment: I see, I apologize

Comment: No need.  I can tell those were sincere questions.  And discussion is always good

Answer (score 3):

## First version

```
max(b.append(g)['age'])
Out[1]:
    44
```

## Second version

```
dict1 = {'Boys': b, 'Girls': g}

max([max(dict1[k]['age']) for k in dict1.keys()])
Out[2]:
    44

max([max(v['age']) for v in dict1.values()])
Out[3]:
    44
```

Comment: That was just a simple example.  In reality I could have hundreds of DFs, not just two.

Comment: Why not just use `v['age']) for v in dict1.values()` iterating through values rather than `keys` ? I like the second approach because it is memory efficient (even though `v['age'].max()` is faster than `max(v['age'])`

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.concat(d.values())
m = df.max()
print(m)

name    Ted
age      44
dtype: object
```

Comment: I guess I made my example too simple.  In reality I could and will have many more columns in the dfs, so would want to specify which one to max, in this case, age.

Answer (score 1):

`np.nanmax` Without an axis it returns the scalar maximum.

```
np.nanmax([df.age.to_numpy() for df in [b,g]])  #much faster on np.array than pd.Series
#44
```